# Android Studio does not mark variables and annotations with color after moving to GitHub

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-build-flavors

I have worked in the past with a local server for a version control for some while. After a couple of months of working this way, we moved to use GitHub and for some reason the compiler does not identify variables and annotations and leaves them white -

[image]

[image]

Example of the intended result -

[image]

**I have tried to do invalidate cache and restart the IDE. This did not solve the issue.**  It seems like there is a file that I missed that configures this kind of thing, but I don't know what it is...

Comment: What's your color scheme in `Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin`?

Comment: @Pawel the scheme is fine, other projects work well. Anyway, after playing a bit with build flavors and variants the problems suddenly disappeared...I have no idea why

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart clears IDE cache, but not the project caches (which is probably the cause). Try this: clean project, gradle sync, rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what fixed the issue but while applying new features, building and cleaning the project multiple times the problem got fixed on it's own.